# Why NSObject returning int, implicit cast error? Some pointer issue w/ ARC?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting, implicit-conversion, nsobject

I have a method which returns a `Card*` NSObject (to be clear, this an object of my own invention, which I correctly and successfully define in my Card.h and Card.m):

```
-(Card*)readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSData *existingData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Deck"];
    // if no such data exists, return nil
    if (existingData == nil)
        return nil;
    NSArray *existingDeck = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:existingData];
    return [existingDeck objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

It seems clear to me that this should return a `Card*`, and yet, when I call it from another method, like this:

```
Card* selectedCard = readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults(indexPath);
```

I get the warning:

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'Card*' is disallowed with Arc

I thought maybe the issue was that I didn't really cast it to a `Card*` before returning, but if I change my `readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults` method to explicitly cast as such, I still get the same warning:

```
Card* thisCard = [existingDeck objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return thisCard;
```

To be clear, I know that this does return a `Card*`, because when I put that same code in the function calling it (instead of separating it into its own `readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults` method) I get the `Card*`.  I am trying to slim down my code by putting this oft-used code portion in its own method and am baffled as to why it does not work.

I have tried returning my entire `NSArray*` of cards instead, but that causes the same warning (just implicit conversion to `NSArray*` instead of to 'Card*').  Existing answers to this warning, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21888493/1586231) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603609/comparing-in-objective-c-implicit-conversion-of-int-to-id-is-disallowed-wi) do not seem related to my situation (unless I am really missing something).

I have 2 ideas regarding what might be happening:

1. Maybe the fact that this data is being accessed elsewhere in order to populate a UITableView is somehow messing up the pointer or something.
2. Maybe ARC is nixing my Card before I can even use it for some baffling reason (this sounds likely because the fact that the compiler seems to think my obviously `Card*` returning method returns an int makes me think I'm getting a pointer and my code for some reason doesn't understand that the pointer points at a `Card*`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel exceedingly foolish.  Then again, Stack Overflow is a place which makes you happy to feel foolish.  The problem was just that I have been coding in c and C# for too long, so I called the method incorrectly.  I should have written:

```
Card* thisCard = [self readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:indexPath];
```

Instead of:

```
Card* selectedCard = readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults(indexPath);
```

Comment: There should also be a warning about an **implicit declaration** of `readCardFromArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults`, which is a little more helpful in this case.

Comment: You're correct.  I foolishly ignored that, thinking I just needed to build->clean as I had only just added the header to my .h.